# Insert with php in mysql from CSV if not exists

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I got a problem and could't find a solution for me.
I want to insert with a php script in my mysql database from a csv file.

The database got a primary key, which is created automatically on every insert.
The csv file grows with time, but the existed date should not be inserted again! I could not check the primary key in this case, because it is generated on every insert.

This is my file so far:

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $import = "INSERT INTO xt_products(
                products_owner, 
                products_quantity, 
                products_shippingtime, 
                products_model,
                products_model_original, 
                products_price, 
                products_tax_class_id
            ) VALUES (
                '$data[0]',
                '$data[1]',
                '$data[2]',
                '$data[3]',
                'wayne_$data[4]',
                '$data[5]',
                '$data[6]'
            )";
    mysql_query($import) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

I know about where exists or if exists bgin end, but I could not get it to work.

Edit: Forgot to mention it, it should check, whether the products_model is already in the database. That would be the $data[3] field there

Comment: Is there a certain field which is duplicate or all?

Comment: have you tried this here ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Forgot to mention it, it should check, whether the products_model is already in the database. That would be the $data[3] field there.

Comment: did a change... had wrong syntax. try now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add the duplicate statement

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $import = "INSERT INTO xt_products(
                                products_owner, 
                                products_quantity, 
                                products_shippingtime, 
                                products_model,
                                products_model_original, 
                                products_price, 
                                products_tax_class_id
                                ) VALUES (
                                        '$data[0]',
                                        '$data[1]',
                                        '$data[2]',
                                        '$data[3]',
                                        '$data[4]',
                                        '$data[5]',
                                        '$data[6]'
                                        )
                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE products_owner='$data[0]'
                ";

    mysql_query($import) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error `you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1=1' at line 18`

Comment: sorry, wrong syntax, try now. Must be `INSERT IGNORE INTO...`

Comment: This does't work either, because everytime I start the import, every row gets a new primary key.

Comment: @CSDev Than you may have to do an update to you db so ther can't be dublicates... more like a unique key over all columns. I provide you with a on duplicate statement... just try it, if it doesn't work... think about the unique thing...

Comment: Ok Thank you very much. I will try this out. The thing with the unique key isn't unfortunately possible.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    include ("config.php"); //Connect to Database


    //Upload File
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'])) {
            echo "<h1>" . "File ". $_FILES['filename']['name'] ." uploaded successfully." . "</h1>";
            echo "<h2>Displaying contents:</h2>";
            readfile($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']);
        }

        //Import uploaded file to Database
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $import="INSERT into table(something,something,something,something,something,something,something) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]','$data[6]','$data[7]')";

    mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
        }

        fclose($handle);

        print "Import done";

        //view upload form
    }else {

        print "Upload new csv by browsing to file and clicking on Upload<br />\n";

        print "<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='import.php' method='post'>";

        print "File name to import:<br />\n";

        print "<input size='50' type='file' name='filename'><br />\n";

        print "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'></form>";

    }



?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die("Could not connect.");

        if(!$db)

        die("no db");
     if(!mysql_select_db("database",$db))

        die("No database selected.");
?>
```